# CLUSTER command for Firebird?

Tags: firebird, clustered-index

PostgreSQL has a [`CLUSTER` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html) that can defrag the data on-demand rather than automatically which kills write speed.

Can Firebird `CLUSTER` on demand?

(I can't find it in the docs, and google searches come up well short.  Pretty cars tho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command for Firebird (which is also the reason you can't find it). Firebird doesn't have clustered indexes, and doesn't have a way to 'fake' them like PostgreSQL does.

Comment: wait, just reread without bleary eyes, so Firebird doesn't defrag at all?

Comment: Firebird doesn't have a defrag, and with a MVCC architecture a defrag isn't really that effective (unless data never changes). Note that `CLUSTER` isn't really a defrag either, it is a way to simulate clustered indexes (and therefor has the effect of a defrag).

Comment: would you mind explaining here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407153/does-firebird-defrag-if-so-like-a-clustered-index  it sounds like a huge performance hit in certain situations

Comment: @Gracchus I have sent a mail with a link to someone who is better at explaining this, if she doesn't respond I will try to answer it.

Comment: i very much appreciate it!